# insert div within an article automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to insert a div within an article using the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvidSlot"></div><div>').insertAfter('#mvp-content-main p:nth-child(1) ');
      $('<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvid1Slot"></div><div>').insertAfter('.mvp-main-box p:nth-child(20) ');
      $('<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvid2Slot"></div><div>').insertAfter('.mvp-main-box p:nth-child(40) ');
      $('<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvid3Slot"></div><div>').insertAfter('.mvp-main-box p:nth-child(60) ');
      $( "<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvidSlot"></div><div>" ).insertAfter( "div.mvp-content-main p:eq(1)" );
});
```

i can get it working on a test page, with some content like:

```
<div class="mvp-main-box">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ex quo intellegitur, quoniam se ipsi omnes natura diligant, tam insipientem quam sapientem sumpturum, quae secundum naturam sint, reiecturumque contraria. 
</div>
```

What I can't do is then make it insert the div into another page where I don't have control of the div class name but I know the name.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you noticed this quotes mismatch: `"<div class="ad` ?

Comment: To get div by name you can use `$('div[name=...]')`.

Comment: Sorry, so you're asking how to insert some content, using jQuery, from one domain to another (where you have absolutely no control)?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I think he meant he is not able to recreate the same stuff in another page(which is probably written by another member on his team). I don't think he wants to modify one webpage from another.

Comment: sorry, i mean i want to insert the div into a page like this , where their div on page are all ready setup and i can change them, 
 http://www.golfwrx.com/525250/3-keys-for-getting-out-of-bunkers-with-soft-sand/?utm_source=Front&utm_medium=Featured_Center_Top&utm_campaign=GolfWRX_OnSite&utm_content=main

Comment: maybe a different way,  what i have above works with: <div class="mvp-main-box">  how do i change it so it works with<div id="mvp-content-main" >   ,  id instead of class?

Comment: anyone got an idea on this, still stuck on it